# Response status of rest api in sharepoint 2013 workflow for breakroleinheritance is forbidden

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, rest, designer-workflow

I am using http web service to break permission inheritance for current item.for that I am using the following sequence.

1) fetching **Request Digest** value using following rest api endpoint:

```
_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "_api/contextinfo"
```

[image]

I am getting `response code :OK` for above query

2) **Break Permission Inheritance** using following endpoint(I am using above request digest in this query):

```
_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('listname')/items(itemId)/breakroleinheritance(copyRoleAssignments=true, clearSubscopes=true)"
```

[image]

I am getting `response code :Forbidden` for above query

**Edit :Things I have already tried**

1. activating feature "workflow can use app permissions".
2. grant full permissions for workflow.
3. adding action in app step.

Comment: Forbidden means the account making the request doesn't have permission to do that.

Comment: What if the account is site collection admin ?

Comment: Is it subsite or site collection where you are creating your workflow?

Comment: Also share the XML you have used in the Permission Request XML field to grant full control permission to the workflow..

Answer (score 0):

Please try enabling this site feature which will allow the workflow to make modifications to list.

[image]

Cheers,

-Drew

Comment: I have already activated this feature

Answer (score 0):

When I do it, I simply just use the parameter `true` like this:

```
/_api/web/lists(guid'#1')/items(#2)/breakroleinheritance(true)
```

This haven't failed me yet.

Comment: I am using this query in designer workflow. I have tried the above URL too.

Comment: I do that as well. Simply replace "breakroleinheritance(copyRoleAssignments=true, clearSubscopes=true)" with "breakroleinheritance(true)" and call the endpoint like any other REST endpoint from a workflow

Comment: That's true. but right now I am getting "Response : {"error":{"code":"-2147024891, System.UnauthorizedAccessException","message":{"lang":"en-US","value":"Access denied. You do not have permission to perform this action or access this resource."}}"

Comment: You also have an x-request header I normally don't use. I only use accept and content-type headers. This at least is a known working format.

Comment: are you using app step or form digest value ? right now I am trying with app step only. Do we  need to specify form digest value for app step ?

Comment: As a rule of thumb I alway use app step for all my webservice requests. Mostly to make sure it works even if the user don't have access to the element I'm trying to get. In this case I wouldn't expect the end user to have access to manipulate the permissions, so I would place this type of call within an app step. No need for digest. It's really that simple. Place the http call within and app step. Add just headers "accept" + "Content-Type" and make the call. Remember it needs to be a POST call.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84032/discussion-between-gopal-zadafiya-and-morten-k).

Answer (score 0):

For reference I think the correct solution is to give the workflow app the necessary permissions

In summary

- In Manage Site Feature, activate feature "workflow can use app step".
- Now go to Site settings -> Site App Permissions , there you will find an entry for Workflow i.t|clientID@tenantID.
- Copy the Client ID and give it full control over site/list etc. To know how to give workflow full access please follow this blog.
  [SharePoint Blog: Item Level Permission - SPD Workflow 2013 - Part 2](http://buildsharepointconcepts.blogspot.com/2017/04/item-level-permission-spd-2013-part-2.html) .
  follow same steps as mentioned for SPD workflow.

  - Add the REST call into the App Step.

The reference is for Nintex but it still applies to OOTB workflows.

See https://community.nintex.com/t5/Nintex-for-Office-365/REST-API-Break-Role-Inheritance-Nintex-O365-not-working/m-p/59359

James